# django: 'has no ForeignKey' Error while running the 'django by example' tutorial code

Tags: python, django, exception, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I am following [this](http://lightbird.net/dbe/todo_list.html#adding-multiple-items) part of the 'django by example' tutorial. Now when I go to `/admin/todo/datetime/` and click on `Add date time` I get this error:

```
Exception Type: Exception at /admin/todo/datetime/add/
Exception Value: <class 'todo.models.Item'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'todo.models.DateTime'>
```

My code is pretty much identical(except that I have the import statements included):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class DateTime(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    def __unicode__(self):
       return unicode(self.datetime)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    priority = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    difficulty = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    done = models.BooleanField(default = False)

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name", "priority", "difficulty", "created", "done"]
    search_fields = ["name"]

class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item

class DateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["datetime"]
    inlines = [ItemInline]

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
admin.site.register(DateTime, DateAdmin)
```

I looked at similar S.O. threads but I can't figure out from there what is going wrong here.
(Btw, I use `django 1.3` while `django 1.2` is used in the turorial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your models don't match those in the tutorial. Your `Item.created` is a `DateTimeField` while their `Item.created` is a `ForeignKey` to the `DateTime` model.

```
# From http://lightbird.net/dbe/todo_list.html#adding-multiple-items

class DateTime(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.datetime)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    created = models.ForeignKey(DateTime)
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    difficulty = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should replace `created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)` with `created = models.ForeignKey(DateTime)` in your `Item` model.